# When SubJoin is used in JSqlParser?

Tags: java, jsqlparser

When parsing a query with JSqlParser, in some cases it seems JSqlParser decides to generate a SubJoin object as a FromItem, instead of the regular Table / Join objects.

Can you please help me understand when it happens and why? What is the main difference between them?
Is it related to the brackets which decide on the order?

Example that gets the parser to create a SubJoin object:

```
SELECT 
    test
FROM
    ((tbl1
    LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON ((tbl1.id = tbl2.id)))
    LEFT JOIN tbl3 ON ((tbl1.id = tbl3.id)))
```

An example that gets the library to create only Join Objects:

```
SELECT 
    test
FROM
    tbl1
        LEFT JOIN
    tbl2 ON tbl1.id = tbl2.id
        LEFT JOIN
    tbl3 ON tbl1.id = tbl3.id;
```

Comment: At first look it depends on the parenthesis around the expression. The subjoin builds a hierarchy of join expressions.

Comment: @wumpz - thanks, so SubJoins are created whenever parenthesis exist, which is probably only when the join order matters?

Comment: You can understand SubJoins as a hierarchical deeper fromItem + JoinExpression - contruct. So SubJoin itself is the parenthesis if you so will. Buf if you are all in visitors, then there should be no problem. Or better: what is the problem you face due to this contruct?

Comment: Thanks. I was just trying to understand the structure. I think it's important even when using the visitors pattern, because even when using it, one needs to know what to look for and where. For example, this far I was looking for joins in the joins array. But then, I ran into a query with parenthesis, and it seems that now I need to search for joins (using accept) in the FromItem part as well, as it can contain a subjoin and not only a Table. Thanks for your help!

Comment: should I make an answer from my comments?

Comment: That would be great, I think your comments were very helpful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **SubJoin** is created if there are parenthesis in your from - part:

```
FROM
    ((tbl1
    LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON ((tbl1.id = tbl2.id)))
    LEFT JOIN tbl3 ON ((tbl1.id = tbl3.id)))
```

You can understand **SubJoin**s as a hierarchical deeper **fromItem** + **JoinExpression** - contruct. So **SubJoin** itself is the parenthesis if you so will.

Buf if you are all in visitors, then there should be no problem. Using JSqlParser versions >0.9, there are adapter classes for visitors, e.g. **ExpressionVisitorAdapter**, which is a standard implementation of the needed visitor.